# Unable to access a different recipients account folders with C# Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to access my spam folder on a different account in my Outlook.
In my Outlook account I have 3 email accounts set, where 2 are work related and 1 is personal.

I managed to acces the emails in my main account by using the following code:

```
ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
items = inbox.Items;
```

This works perfectly. 
However, when I try to access a different account, I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The operation failed because of a registry or installation problem. Restart Outlook and try again. If the problem persists, reinstall.'
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient Recipient, OlDefaultFolders FolderType) 
>      at DemoAntiSpam2.ThisAddIn.ThisAddIn_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\T\DemoAntiSpam2\DemoAntiSpam2\ThisAddIn.cs:line 29 
>      at Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInImpl.OnStartup() 
>      at DemoAntiSpam2.ThisAddIn.FinishInitialization() in C:\Projects\T\DemoAntiSpam2\DemoAntiSpam2\ThisAddIn.Designer.cs:line 57 
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.ExecuteEntryPoints()

```
Outlook.NameSpace ns;
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
Outlook.Items items;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    var recipient = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientAddress);
    recipient.Resolve();
    if (recipient.Resolved)
    {
        // Code breaks here.
        inbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        items = inbox.Items;
        items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue with the following:

[https://www.codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/668606/Outlook-interop-GetSharedDefaultFolder-The-operati#ctl00_ctl00_MC_AMC_Answers_ctl01_A_Title)

Instead of accessing the folders with `GetSharedDefaultFolder()`, I looked up the index of the namespace folders:

```
Outlook.NameSpace ns = Application.GetNamespace("Mapi");
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = ns.Folders[recipient].Folders["Ongewenste e-mail"];
```

The folder name is the direct name you use in your outlook. You can also use the `EntryId` which is a unique Id for the object.